# Changing raster color ramp and removing layer name in Legend using ArcPy with ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

I am using ArcMap 10.8.

I am pretty new to Python programming and I have a code that updates the layout view legend with new Min-Max values whenever a new raster is added to the TOC.

```py
import arcpy

#get mxd object
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
#get data frame
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)
#get legend
legend = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "LEGEND_ELEMENT")[0]
  
#add new items to legend
legend.autoAdd = True
```

But I wanted to see if I can change the color ramp and remove the layer name from the legend using arcpy. Here is a screenshot example below:

[image: Example]

So whenever a new raster layer is added, it defaults back to the grey scale.